# Why can't the TFS command line tool find my project?

Tags: tfs

I'm using the TFS command line utility, "tf.exe"  This command:

```
tf.exe dir /folders /server:[my server] /login:[my login] $/WebSite
```

Always returns this:

```
No items match $/WebSite
```

I know for a fact that my project exists and is called "WebSite".  I can browse it fine from Visual Studio, so I know I have permissions to it.

Why would the command line utility not find it?

(It is part of a project collection.  Would this change the naming of the project?)

Comment: I figured it out.  Project collections are added to the end of the server name, which I wasn't doing.

Comment: Add that as an answer, and select it as the answer.  That way if others have the same problem, they can see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Project collections are added to the end of the server name, which I wasn't doing.